# Spring Data JPA save child object with the ID of parent object

Tags: spring, database, spring-data-jpa, persistence, h2

I have two objects, one parent and one child as follows :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class CategoryModel {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<AttributeModel> attributes;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="attribute")
public class AttributeModel {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
    private CategoryModel category;
}
```

I also have dtos which maps to these model objects but I ommited them.
When I try to save a category object with this payload Attribute values are also created in the attribute table but with *null* category ids.

```
{
    "name":"Chemicals",
    "attributes":[
        {"name": "volume"}, {"name":"humidity"}
    ]
}
```

What can I do to have my attribute values persisted into the database with the category id which is created before them?

Comment: please also share the code through which you are persisting category and attributes in the database.

Comment: I did not write any code for saving the entities to the database. I am using a CrudRepository defined like this : public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<CategoryModel, Long> . I use this interface's save method.

Comment: Can you show the code you wrote in a service? Probably, the problem is in the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by manually setting child object's reference to the parent object as follows :

```
public Long createCategory(CategoryDto categoryDto) {
    CategoryModel categoryModel = categoryDto.toModel(true,true);
    categoryModel.getAttributes().forEach(a -> a.setCategory(categoryModel));
    return categoryRepository.save(categoryModel).getId();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this problem is not a "Spring Data JPA" problem, it is a JPA (probably Hibernate) problem.

---

### Analysis

Since you left out the code for the controller and the JSON mapping, I have to guess a bit:

- fact 1: **The relationship between *category* and *attributes* is controlled by the attribute `AttributeModel.category` but not by `CategoryModel.attributes`. (That is how JPA works).**
- *observation 2:* Your JSON object define `CategoryModel.attributes`  (i.e. opposite to how JPA works).

Without knowing your JSON mapping configuration and controller code, I would **guess** that the problem is: that **your JSON mapper does not set the `AttributeModel.category` field when it deserialises the JSON object.**

---

### Solution

So you need to instruct the JSON mapper to set the `AttributeModel.category` field during deserialisation. If you use Jackson, you could use:

- `@JsonManagedReference` and
- `@JsonBackReference`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class CategoryModel {
    ...    

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<AttributeModel> attributes;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="attribute")
public class AttributeModel {
    ...

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
    private CategoryModel category;
}
```

Comment: I did it manually by setting attributes model to the desired category, I think what you proposed is the same.

Comment: @cuneytyvz: "I did it manually by setting attributes model to the desired category," did you do this before you asked the question - or after my answer - and does it solve the problem? -- If not, please post the controller and dao code

Comment: I did this and saw your reply later. I added an answer.